# Blotted out thoughts

Tags: rhyme

| My rhymes got blacked out and mixed up! | Can you get them intact and fixed up? |
| --- | --- |
| Live on stage, that idol's new. | ███████████████████████ay. |
| Too low, maybe sing a little higher. | ███████████████████████ge. |
| Gore and guts are common in the Mob. | ███████████████████████ir. |
| Heaven in a cup, to this dessert I pray. | ███████████████████████it. |
| Arrive at the theater and let's all head to war! | ███████████████████████ol. |
| Do a sentence without bail, | ███████████████████████p. |
| Run or back out and you're a pig. | ███████████████████████re. |
| See all the docks by the sea, | ███████████████████████s. |
| For the revolution, the royalty's heads flew. | ███████████████████████t. |
|  |  |
| When you are finished looking at the ends, | At the beginning of each line you should notice some trends. |
| The final answer? It's easy to parse. | It should describe the finished state of these bars. |

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The matched up rhymes and the meaning of the penultimate line:

> Live (5) on stage that idol's new. -> debut -> 5th letter = T
>
> Too (2) low, maybe sing a little higher. -> choir -> 2nd letter = H
>
> Gore (4) and guts are common in the Mob. -> macabre -> 4th letter = A
>
> Heaven (7) in a cup, to this dessert I pray. -> parfait -> 7th letter = T
>
> Arrive (5) at the theater and let's all head to war! -> corps -> 5th letter = S
>
> Do (2) a sentence without bail, -> gaol -> 2nd letter = A
>
> Run (1) or back out and you're a pig. -> renege -> 1st letter = R
>
> See (3) all the docks by the sea, -> quay -> 3rd letter = A
>
> For (4) the revolution, the royalty's heads flew. -> coup -> 4th letter = P

So the solution is:

> THAT'S A RAP

Comment: Oh well done. I felt like I looked at every combination of using the words at the start as guides to which letter to take out of which solution in which order, but everything I tried ended up as rubbish!

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer only.

> It appears that the words in the blacked out boxes have got mixed up so the rhymes don't match with the lines on the left hand side. It also looks as though the lines on the left hand side might clue words with unexpected spellings / pronunciations.

I found the following words, listing the left hand rhymes in order from 1-9:

> ...ir.  2 choir
>  ...it.  4 parfait
>  ...ol.  6 gaol
>  ...ge.  7 renege
>  ...ay.  8 quay
>  ...p.   9 coup
>
>  This leaves:
>  ...re., ...s. and ...t. which must match lines 1, 3 and 5 but I can't figure those out.
>
>   EDIT: Hat tip to JS1 who provided 1: debut, 3: macabre, 5: corps.

Then I looked at:

> lyrics that include lines ending in those words, I found the following:
>  2 All God's creatures got a place in the choir (Celtic Thunder)
>  4 An' bring you a rainbow parfait (Perry Como)
>  7 I am you, now that's a thought to renege (PM Dawn)
>  8 To a little place I've found down by the quay (Chris de Burgh)

but again I can't find suitable matches for the others.

Am I on the right lines at all here?

Comment: All correct so far for the first part!

Comment: Line 1: rot13(qrohg), Line 3: rot13(znpnoer), Line 5: rot13(pbecf)

Comment: Thanks @JS1. This rhyming thing definitely depends on your accent - the line 3 suggestion doesn't rhyme for me (British English) in the slightest, although I have heard others pronouncing the word that way (probably US English).

Comment: I just noticed: rot13(Ng gur ortvaavat bs rnpu yvar, gur svefg jbeq eulzrf jvgu n ahzore.  Yvir->svir, Gbb->gjb, Tber->sbhe, Urnira->frira, Neevir->svir, Qb->Gjb, Eha->Bar, Frr->Guerr, Sbe->sbhe, Jura->gra).  Not sure what it means yet.

Comment: @JS1 Seems very likely that's related to the second half of the penultimate line of the poem....but I can't make anything useful out of it.